# Count sub arrays with atmost k odd numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I recently encountered a question as follows.

Given an array, count number of distinct sub-arrays which have at most m odd numbers.

I know how to solve for exactly m odd numbers. Was wondering can this be solved in *O(n)* too? Any ideas?

Comment: Should the sub-arrays be distinct as pairs of indices of endpoints, or distinct by contents?

Comment: By distinct I mean, the sequence should be unique. If we have two sub-arrays [1,3,2] and [1,2,3]. They will count as distinct.

Comment: Could you please share your O(n) solution for exactly m odd numbers?

Comment: As you need to check distinct by contents, there is no way you can count them without comparing their contents, it´s not possible to make it O(n)

Answer (score 2):

The solution for exactly `m` odd numbers likely finds, for each starting point `i`, the rightmost endpoint `r(i)` of such a sub-array.

What's left is to say that, for at most `m` odd numbers, each starting point `i` has `r(i) - i + 1` possibilities for an endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get that but how to guarantee distinct sub-arrays? I am still thinking about how to handle the distinct sub-array case in better than O(n^2)

Comment: @JohnDoe OK, please clarify the question then. See my comment, "distinct" is ambiguous.